# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error when creating thread

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm not sure how to debug this error since it can be caused by a lot of things. What I was able to do is comment out parts of the program and compiling it repeatedly in order to trace which part of the program produced the error, and I think this part produces the error:

Here I want to create a thread:

```
int j = 0; //not the actual value, just showing that j is of type int
pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, strikeMultiples, (void*)j);
```

Maybe it could also be caused by the strikeMultiples function, which is invoked when the thread is created:

```
static void* strikeMultiples(void* prime) {
    int * primej = (int *) prime;
    int j = *primej;
    free (prime);
    int k;
    for (k = 2; j * k <= NROF_SIEVE; k++) {
        BIT_CLEAR(buffer[(j * k)/64], (j * k)%64);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Assuming `j` is `int`, you're not passing an `int*` to `pthread_create`, thus the buildup of `primej` and subsequent dereference in the thread proc are wrong. `int j = (int)prime;` is closer to reality, but still not "correct". To do it correctly, both `j` inbound and `j` in the proc should be `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`, and the `free` should be removed regardless. That said, it's all speculation, as we don't know what type `j` is on the first snippet, nor where it comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you pass an `int` to the function (casted to a `void *`) and then subsequently try to read it as an `int *`.

Also, you're attempting to `free` something that was not returned from `malloc` and family.

Pass the address of the `int` value, and don't `free` it in the function.  Also, it's not necessary to cast between a `void *` and any non-function pointer.

```
static void* strikeMultiples(void* prime) {
    int *primej = prime;
    int j = *primej;
    int k;
    for (k = 2; j * k <= NROF_SIEVE; k++) {
        BIT_CLEAR(buffer[(j * k)/64], (j * k)%64);
    }
    return NULL;
}

...

pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, strikeMultiples, &j);
```

Comment: Note: care should be taken that `j` in the thread-creator does NOT encounter automatic destruction (fall out of scope) prior to the last usage in the thread. Race conditions passing addresses of local automatic vars to thread-creation are *easy* to do accidentally, and often *difficult* to track down due to their sporadic failure nature. Passing `j` by value such as `intptr_t or `unintptr_t`, or dynamic memory freed by the thread, or a number of other options, will protect against this